# Correlation of Ornstein Uhlenbeck process with white noise

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

We have an OU process fulfilling the following SDE

$dx_t=A(t)x_tdt+S(t)\xi_tdt$,

where $\xi_t$ is a (Gaussian) white noise, $<\xi_t\xi_s>=\delta(t-s)$. What is the correlation between $x_t$ and $\xi_s$($<x_t\xi_s>=?$)?

For $t<s$ it is definitely zero, and for later times?

Comment: You mean $dx_t=A(t)x_tdt+S(t)d\xi_t$, right ? In that case, $d\langle{x_t,\xi_t}\rangle = S_td\langle{\xi_t,\xi_t}\rangle$.

Comment: Hmmm, but then, in your example $\xi_t$ is a Wiener process, not a white noise, or? And I wanted have a correlation for different times t and s: <x_t\chi_s> (in your comment t=s?)

Comment: I supposed that it is a temporal Gaussian white noise. This means that for $s,t \in \mathbb{R}^+$, we have $d\langle{x_t, \xi_s}\rangle = S_t\langle{\xi_t, \xi_s}\rangle = S_t\delta(t-s)$.